# Analytic continuation of the many-body spectral density

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, correlation-functions, many-body, analyticity

For an observable $A$, define the real-time autocorrelation function
$$
C(t) = \langle A A(t) \rangle_{\beta} = \dfrac{1}{Z} \mathrm{Tr}\left[ e^{-\beta H} A e^{i H t} A e^{-i H t}\right],
$$
with $Z = \mathrm{Tr}\left[ e^{-\beta H}\right]$, and the spectral function $S(\omega)$ as its Fourier transform,
$$
S(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-i \omega t} C(t) \mathrm{d} t.
$$
For real $\omega$, we can write this in terms of the spectral representation,
$$
S(\omega) = \sum_{n} p_{n} \sum_{m} |A_{nm}|^{2} \delta(\omega - \omega_{nm}),
$$
where $n$ indexes the Hamiltonian eigenstates $|E_{n}\rangle$ with eigenvalue $E_{n}$, $p_{n} = e^{-\beta E_{n}} / Z$ is the thermal occupation probability, $A_{nm} = \langle E_{n} | A | E_{m} \rangle$, and $\omega_{nm} = E_{n} - E_{m}$.

I am interested in continuing $S(\omega)$ to the complex plane. Is this possible to do in general, and if so, can we say anything about the analytic structure of this continuation? For example, should we expect any poles?

From the fluctuation-dissipation theorem,
$$
S(\omega) = 2(n_{B}(\omega) + 1) \chi^{''}(\omega),
$$
where $n_B$ is the Bose occupation function and $\chi^{''}(\omega) = \mathrm{Im} \chi(\omega)$ is the dissipative part of the response function, it seems like we should maybe expect poles along the imaginary axis at the bosonic Matsubara frequencies. But I'm not sure about the analytic structure of $\chi^{''}(\omega)$ across the whole complex plane. (Perhaps the Kramers-Kronig relations can help to define such a continuation?)

Comment: Perhaps this could help: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/541896/247642

Comment: Thanks Roger. In fact, I was interested by your statement in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/605662/46753) answer that the spectral function is analytic. Would you mind expanding on that?

Comment: Usually people try to do the analytic continuation in the opposite direction https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.04572

Comment: Usually one discusses poles in Green's functions (time-ordered or retarded/advanced) which differ from the spectral function in that they explicitly have a denominator when written in frequency space.

Comment: Also https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/605651/247642 here the spectral function is Lorentz.

Comment: @Anyon Yes, that does seem to be the typical direction if you are interested in getting some practical information out about physical spectral functions. I should clarify that I'm not necessarily interested in analytically continuing the spectral function of a specific model. I'm more interested in whether we can say anything about the general structure of these analytic continuations, if they exist. For example, should we always expect poles in a certain region of the complex plane (e.g. the imaginary axis)?

Comment: @RogerVadim Yes, most of the discussion I have seen has been about the pole structure of Green's functions or response functions, rather than spectral functions — hence the question! For the example you linked with a Lorentzian spectral function, am I understanding correctly that this is for a non-equilibrium system? If so, can one also get poles at arbitrary locations in the complex plane for equilibrium correlation functions? Linking to my previous comment, I am most interested in whether we can constrain the possible location of poles of the spectral function based on general considerations

Comment: You can obtain level broadening also for equilibrium system. Spectral function is essentially matrix elements - so non-analyticity is really that of the matrix elements, and may be dependent on the interactions you have, dimensionality of the system, etc.